# swiftUI NavigationView centered logo righ and right button

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I am trying to make a NavigationView in SwiftUI that has a logo centered and a button right justified.

Here is what I have tried with no success.  I cannot figure out how to remove the title and replace it with a image logo.

[image]

```
.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            }) {
    Image("mylogo")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 154, height: 42)
    Button(action: {
    
        // Actions
    }, label: { Image("hamburger_menu")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
    })
})
```

And this:

[image]

```
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
            HStack {
                Image("mylogo")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 154, height: 42, alignment: .center)
    
                Image("hamburger_menu")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 48, height: 48, alignment: .trailing)
            }
        }
    }
```

It works ok with text as seen here:

[image]

```
    .navigationBarTitle("Text", displayMode: .inline)
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
    
    } ) {
        Image("hamburger_menu")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
    } )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use principal for logo and primary action for button, like (simplified):

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Image("mylogo")
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
        Button(action: {
    
        } ) {
          Image("hamburger_menu")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh great you are wonderful, that worked!!!!   Thank you SOOO much, it was driving me crazy.  One last quick question if you do not mind, how would I go about extending the background color behind the text and buttons up above out of the safe area and up into the stars bar?